# Any better ways to anti-alias text on .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I want to anti-alias like on this screenshot:

[image]

I've tried all the TextRenderingHints, but it still looks bad. *Notice that when I did the screenshot the PNG smoother it*, but you can still see that the second text isn't as good as the first.
Here's my code:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    try {
        SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        PrivateFontCollection fonts;
        FontFamily family = LoadFontFamily(Properties.Resources.SegoeWP_Light, out fonts);
        Font font = new Font(family, 18);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Downloads", font, solidBrush, new PointF(135, 80));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is there a different way to smooth fonts on WinForms (.NET 2.0) ?

Comment: I had the same problem,but i dont remember explicit solution,there must be a property that responsible for GDI or GDI+ will draw graphics.

Comment: Use TextRenderer.DrawText() instead.  You also need to use a ClearType tuner, take the first Google hit.

Comment: @Hans Passant: DrawText() gives me a bold output: http://i42.tinypic.com/1z39ksi.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Photoshop does oversampling. You might not be able to get results quite as good as Photoshop -- it's got better algorithms for pixel snapping, and it probably does things like grow the outlines slightly to get a darker result -- but if `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` (as George suggested) isn't enough, you can try these steps to see if they get the results you want.

1. Create a new `Font` with a size twice as big as what you want to end up with.
2. Measure the text using the larger font, and create a `Bitmap` of that size. Make sure to create it using a format that supports alpha transparency.
3. Draw the text to your `Bitmap` (at (0, 0)). (You probably want to use `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias` here.)
4. Draw the `Bitmap` to your final target, resizing it down by 50%. Make sure to use a high-quality resizing mode.

This will give more of the "smooth" effect from your sample image, because you're basically drawing to a sub-pixel grid. Your results may vary, though -- you might need to draw at (0, 1) instead of (0, 0) to get it to look sharp enough, and you may need to tweak the font size. You could even try drawing at 3x instead of 2x, but you won't get much benefit from going farther than that.

The big concern would be that your text might not come out dark enough -- if lines draw at 1 pixel wide in the 2x size, then they'll only be 50% black in the final result. The best way to deal with this is to pick a font with thicker lines. You could also try overdrawing the text in your `Bitmap` -- draw it once at (0, 0), then again at (0, 1) or (1,0) -- to see if that thickens the lines enough to look good once you size it back down. You'll have to experiment.

I wouldn't recommend this for general-purpose text drawing (where the user selects the layout and the font size), but if you can be in full control of the font size, you can probably tweak this to get pretty good results.

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought the below would have been enough.

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
```

If not maybe try the sample on the page below with no changes, then gradually add in your changes until it breaks.

[How to: Use Antialiasing with Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a619zh6z.aspx)

Comment: As I said: I've tried all the TextRenderingHints, but it still looks bad.

Comment: Sorry, saw than when i re-read your post, i've edited it with another suggestion, which i think is probably your only other option.